# MAC OS Cannot access Windows 7 shared Folders/Files

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, mac, network-shares

I have a shared drive I: in Windows 7, I want to access that drive from my Mac, but I am not able to connect to my windows. From Finder > Go > Connect to server

---

- smb://server

---

It asks me for a Name and Password, I am entering name/passowrd that I used for my Windows account, but nothing happens after I click connect.

I can access internet on both my Windows 7 PC and Mac. I can ping from PC to mac and mac to PC What settings I need to get to that folder in Windows 7?